# how does private and public access work during the compilation in c++

Tags: c++, g++

I know that "public"  let the programmer to have access to members, attributes or other classes and "private" don't let access.

But i wanted to know, how does it actually work during the compilation (g++) ?

I badly explain my question.
I know what will be the effect, i just wanted more information about what the compiler will do, which action to permit public or private access.

Comment: +1:. Downvoters, please don't be harsh. This looks to be a valid question to a curious mind, except that, this requires extensive details on compiler development and may be off topic for SO.

Comment: @Abhijit That's not harsh, but simply expresses this question is unsuitable for SO as it is. It will be hard to explain and cover all the aspects a compiler implementation has to respect to in a useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare (or define) an object, the compiler creates some sort of internal record containing the attributes of that object. For a C++ compiler, one of those attributes will describe the accessibility of a member object. Then, when the compiler encounters code that attempts to access a member, it checks that identity of the code (part of class/part of derived class/neither) against the accessibility attribute to determine whether the access is allowed.

It's impossible to go into much more detail than that though, because the details will vary between compilers.

If you want to get into a really detailed explanation specifically for g++, that's going to get difficult and ugly. The problem is that the code for the g++ AST is (or at least originally was) written in C, but the nodes in the tree are basically polymorphic. To manage that, they have a (fairly large) set of macros to simulate something similar to a dynamic_cast in C++. Each type of node gets assigned an ID, so the macro checks that the node contains the correct ID to signify the type you're trying to access, and gives you access to the data if it's the correct type.

Among those macros are a number of predicate macros that will let you query whether a particular node has some particular property. It's been long enough since I've looked that I can't *guarantee* it, but if memory serves one of those will let you query the accessibility of a name.

Comment: @Laykker Thats not a description of the effect, what he tells you is how it is implemented: it boils down to a simple if.